# Library linking in C++, dependence between three libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, circular-dependency

This might be a weird / beginners question for someone. However I have the following situation.

In my code, I am creating three libraries, lets say **A**,**B** and **C**. In library B i am linking library A, so something like `target_link_libraries(... A)`.

My C library is linking against B. So I have:
`B -> A`
`C -> B`.

Should it then be possible, that I use methods, enums whatever defined in library A also in C? Although C is not linking A explicitly? I was using an enum defined in library A in C, `A::someClass::someEnum` and it compiled and showed correct value entries.

Comment: Using a enum doesn't require linking a library. Including a header is enough.

Answer (score 1):

> Should it then be possible, that I use methods, enums whatever defined in library A also in C?

Does your C library uses these methods/enums/etc. via **including a header** from the library A or from the library B?

If C **directly** includes the header from the library A, then it should be linked with the library A **explicitly**:

```
# A is a private linkage of B.
target_link_libraries(B PRIVATE A)
# C needs to be linked with A
target_link_libraries(C B A)
```

If C includes the header from the library B, which in turn includes the header from the library A, then A library should be a part of the B **interface**:

```
# B links with A and this linkage is an interface of B
target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC A)
# C may link with B only
target_link_libraries(C B)
```

These approaches assume "modern" (**target**-oriented) CMake to be used. But using these approaches one would get most scalable solution.

Comment: Yes I am including headers from A in my C library. It is your first case. I also thought I have to include them, however I was confused when it worked without and compiled without

Comment: "I was confused when it worked without" - There is some difference between "worked" and "correct". "**worked**" means it works in **particular case** with **particular environment** (specific OS, distro, other settings). "Working" in one case doesn't imply it would work in the other case, even with a little change of environment. But "**correct**" means it would work in **all cases** with **all environments**. If you don't want to check and debug every modification in environment, the it is better to write "correct" code.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that linkage dependency and compilation dependency are not the same thing.

It's quite possible that the sources of library C use definitions from headers associated with library A... irrespective of whether C depends on A when linking.

Now, in CMake, we use `target_link_libraries()` not only for linking. This CMake command makes sure that the library's headers are available to the dependent target, for compilation, and that its libraries are available for linking.

<sub>It's also possible for library C to require library A for linking - to have the definitions of, say, functions or variables from library A. Libraries can theoretically have circular link dependencies (which means that you need to either link against the entire circle, or no part of it).</sub>

Comment: So if I just include headers from library A it should work like this? In what case should I then also link C against A?

Comment: @malajedala: You typically don't link libraries at all - you link executables, using libraries. So I'm not sure I understand your question.